# Section Headers in UITableView when inset of tableview is changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I have implemented a "Pull to refresh" in my tableView like the iPhone app Twitter or Facebook.
My tableView has sections with head views. When the tableView is in "Refresh mode", so when I pulled the tableView to refresh, I set the contentInset of the tableView to display the tableView a certain way. At this moment, if I push the tableView up, the headers of the UITableView are not anymore scrolling to the top of the UITableView. See the following screenshots:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

How can I fix that to make the headers scroll like expected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same problem when using contentInset and fixed it by adding code to scrollViewDidScroll: to update the contentInset dynamically while in the "loading" state.

```
if( refreshState == kLoading ) {
    if( scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 0 )
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    else
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake( MIN( -scrollView.contentOffset.y, kPullHeight ), 0, 0, 0 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can't wait to try that!! Can you shed some lights on me and explain me what is kPullHeight?

Comment: This trick makes the scrolling lose its inertia when the user lifts its finger when the pull to refresh view becomes visible.

Comment: You sir, saved my bacon.

Comment: what tis the kpullheight

Comment: what is value of kPullHeight ?

Comment: It's the height of your "Reload to Refresh" view

Answer (score 3):

When doing this, I usually use the table-wide header in UITableView instead:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableHeaderView
```

...instead of contentInsets. There were a lot of bugs with contentInsets all the way back to iOS 2.x days, and I'm not sure they've all been fixed. Is there a reason you can't use a table header?

Comment: Do you have an implementation of a pull-to-refresh UITableView using the tableHeaderView?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to add push view controller.

- Create a table view controller and add it as the sub view of existing view controller.
- Then assign your table view and refresh controllers to tableview controller's properties.

  ```
  UITableViewController *newTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
  newTableViewControler.tableView = <yourTableView>;

  <yourRefreshController> = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
  [<yourRefreshController> addTarget:self
                              action:@selector(refreshTableView:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

  newTableViewController.refreshControl = _chatListRefreshControl;
  [self addChildViewController:newTableViewController];
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an UIKit bug. Found a workaround:

```
// your initial inset
let kInset = 40.0

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if (offset < 0) {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: kInset, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
    } else {
        scrollView.contentInset = .zero
    }
}
```