# UiTableView header not disappearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView configured as plain style so I can have the header views stuck on the top of the table until another header pulls it away.

The problem is: If I have a header stuck on the top of the screen, and I programmatically scroll to another part of the table (where that header should not appear at all), that UIView will not be dismissed. I.e. if I scroll again to that part of the table, a ghost of that header will be visible on that part of the table.

[image: See screenshot]

I've implemented the method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingHeaderView:(nonnull UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section` to understand what is happening. I found that if I manually scroll until a header is pull away of the screen, this delegate is called. But if I scroll programmatically, the delegate is not called.

By the way, I tried scrolling programmatically using two different methods, and the problem is the same.

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

One workaround that I can imagine is implementing `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;`, filtering all the header views that are outside the visible screen, and removing them from superview. I can probably make it work, but I would like to know if there is any other better solution.

[EDIT] If I call `- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated;` with animated = YES, the bug does not happen. I can go with this solution, but I really would like in some cases to scroll without animation.

Comment: does the issue occur if you set the table view as grouped not plain?

Comment: No, i've just tested it. The problem occurs when the header is out of its "natural" position (it is stuck on the top of the table), which will not happen in the grouped style.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466097/section-headers-in-uitableview-when-inset-of-tableview-is-changed this may point you in the right direction

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not playing with contentInset in my implementation.

Comment: Oh my god, as I said, I use `[_conversationTableView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:mustAnimate];` to scroll the table automatically. And I just realized that if animated is YES, the bug does not happen! I will edit the question to mention that. But at this point, I can only think that it is an iOS bug.

Comment: Try throwing the contentOffset in a separate animation to retain the "animation" effect while still setting `animated:NO`. Glad you found an easy workaround hopefully I was able to help

Comment: I will try @WillVonUllrich, thank you very much for the help.
Last question (I will edit it and remove it after your answer): How do I gain reputation here? I really would like to comment in some questions, but I don't have enough rep to do so :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast  Really take's time more than anything, but consistent, positive content is the best way to go. Commenting, answering, up-voting (when appropriate), and most importantly **asking good questions** will give you plenty of reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Do NOT explicitly scroll the table view between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

**Explanation**

I'm using NSFetchedResultsController to populate the table. These are my implementations for some of the methods of NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [_conversationTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [_conversationTableView endUpdates];
}
```

The problem is that endUpdates was making a chain of calls that ended calling my method `[self scrollToBottom]` (which was a very ugly code actually). This method, as the name says, calls `- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated;` to scroll the table view to the bottom of the table.

The explicit scrolling of the table during a `beginUpdates` - `endUpdates` was the culprit of my whole problem.

**Solution**

Scrolling the table view only after finishing endUpdates.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [_conversationTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [_conversationTableView endUpdates];

    [self scrollToBottom];
}
```

**Side Note**

This also fixed a problem where the table view was sometimes flickering when scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand your issue entirely but it seems that your header view(s) (some `UIView`) is/are not rendered correctly once you programmatically scroll away from this area / section and **then** return.

I'm not sure how you are filling your header view content but I have *several* applications running `UITableView`'s with multiple section headers that require updating for scrolling / content offset's with no problem, **as long as** you "draw" your headers with this delegate:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Per section, simply return the appropriate header view

    ...

    NSString *someIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sectionHeaderView:<some #, letter, or tag>", <SOMETHING UNIQUE ADD HERE>];
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *myHeaderView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:someIdentifier];

    if (!myHeaderView) {

        // No header view found with that ID. Make a new one 

    }

    ... 

    return myHeaderViewForSection;

}
```

This way whether you finger scroll **or** programmatically set the content offset which ever way you like, your table view will know what to draw, when to draw it, and where to put it.

Using their delegates is a bit of a drag as it's slightly tedious at start, but using the `viewForHeaderInSection` proved the only way I ever obtained the results I (you) wanted.

Hope this helps - happy coding!

Comment: I'm using this method. However, maybe I'm doing something that I shouldn't. I'm setting the frame of the cell inside this method.
`-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
...
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
... return view;}
`

Comment: Setting the frame shouldn't be an issue as long as it remains constant for all cells / sections. I would use "unique" identifiers for each `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` that way the table *really* knows which is which

Comment: What do you mean by unique identifiers for each UITableViewHeaderFooterView? Can you point me a document to read about it?

Comment: Sure - here's Apple's doc's for it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614921-register   What I've noticed is that if you give each header view the same ID, let's say "sectionHeaderView", the table may juggle many views it see's with the same reuseID and become unsure as to where to draw what.

Comment: I updated my answer with a bit more context as to what I mentioned above here - should make things more clear :)

Comment: Well, I'm already using this method. The only difference is that I'm using registerForClass instead of registerForNib. I've tried registering the class only once and dequeueing them inside `viewForHeaderInSection`, and also tried registering the class every time inside `viewForHeaderInSection` with a different identifier. The problem occurs in both cases.

Comment: I will try your recommendation.

Comment: Lastly, if you are providing a header/footer, you don't need to call `willDisplay..` or `didEndDisplaying...` these should be called automatically in the background by your table / scroll view

Comment: I followed your suggestion and the problem persists. Just to make it clear, it is like the UIView of my customHeader is forgotten in the place it was before. If keep doing it over and over I will be duplicating that header view forever. Let me take a screenshot and update my question.

Comment: I found the real solution, that workaround was still failing for some cases. I will post my solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Manually set the sectionHeader height to 0 when it should not appear

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0;
```